# Spring Boot 2 Oauth Infinite Redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm struggling to upgrade an application from Spring Boot 1.5 to Spring Boot 2 that uses OAuth and a custom authorization server.

The OAuth flow is functioning correctly using the auth server and in its spring boot 1.5 setup. However after migrating to spring boot 2 (2.1.3 currently).

I'm getting an infinite redirect between the auth server and the client application. The redirects proceed as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/
http://localhost:8080/login
https://auth.example.com/oauth/authorize?...
http://localhost:8080/login?code=[code1]&state=[state]
http://localhost:8080/login
https://auth.example.com/oauth/authorize?...
http://localhost:8080/login?code=[code1]&state=[state]
http://localhost:8080/login
https://auth.example.com/oauth/authorize?...
http://localhost:8080/login?code=[code1]&state=[state]
http://localhost:8080/login
https://auth.example.com/oauth/authorize?...
http://localhost:8080/login?code=[code1]&state=[state]
...
```

As you can see, once the auth server redirects back to the login with the auth code on the query string, the client application then just redirects back to `/login` restarting the whole process, it then redirects infinitely until the browser calls a stop to it.

I have stripped the applicaiton back to the bare bones, here is my configuraiton:

Applicaiton.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{

   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      SpringApplication.run( AdminApplication.class, args );
   }

}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

   @Override
   protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
   {
      http.antMatcher( "/**" )
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers( "/assets/**", "/app/**", "/login*" ).permitAll()
               .anyRequest().authenticated();
   }

}
```

application.yml

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: xxxxxx
      clientSecret: xxxxx
      accessTokenUri: https://auth.example.com/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://auth.example.com/oauth/authorize
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://auth.example.com/user
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to my issue, it turns out that Spring Boot 2 seems to not default to use the `Authorization` header when requesting the access token, adding the following config property resolved the issue

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      authenticationScheme: header
```